# How do I evaluate the sum $\sum_{i=1}^m \left[ \sum_{j=1}^n (i+j) \right]$?

Tags: summation

I can't understand what this composition of summations practically says? Can someone explain it to me and if they can evaluate it?
$$\sum_{i=1}^m \left[ \sum_{j=1}^n (i+j) \right]$$

Comment: Nested summations is this $(a+b)+(c+d)$, which you know is the same as putting the parentheses in any other position and/or reordening the numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Evaluate the inner sum first.

$$\sum_{j = 1}^n (i + j) = \sum_{j = 1}^n i + \sum_{j = 1}^n j = ni + \frac{n(n+1)}{2}.$$

Now you take the sum of $ni + \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$ from $i = 1$ to $m$.

$$\sum_{i = 1}^m \left[ni + \frac{n(n+1)}{2}\right] = n\sum_{i = 1}^m i + \sum_{i = 1}^m \frac{n(n+1)}{2} = n\frac{m(m+1)}{2} + m\frac{n(n+1)}{2} = \frac{nm(m + n + 2)}{2}$$

So you have

$$\sum_{i = 1}^n \left[\sum_{j = 1}^n (i + j)\right] = \frac{nm(n+m+2)}{2}$$

Comment: why did you put ni at the first summation?